# Not getting previous state name after the page has been reloaded[Using F5 key]

Tags: angularjs, angular1.6

I need a way to go back to a previous state after the current page has been reloaded.

I have multiple solutions but they have some limitation:

**1) history.back();**

- It is not working when the user will remove it's browser's history.

**2) Using `stateChangeSuccess`**

> $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
>
> });

- Not getting state name after current page is reloaded.

**AC:**

1) Always get the previous state name after the page is reloading.

Comment: Try this `console.log(from.name);`

Comment: You can also try timeout if there is an issue.

Comment: Insert the previous state name as a query parameter `http://localhost/#!/main/whatever?previous=main.another`.

Comment: @jsruok Yes it working but I have 3 more parameters in the same URL so it looks very long. If you have any other solution then please inform me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $localStorage.

**page 1:**

```
$localStorage.previousState = 'page1'
```

**page 2:**

```
if ($localStorage.previousState) {
   $state.go($localStorage.previousState);
   delete $localStorage.previousState
}
```